# StackOverflowException when trying to assign public value to private backing field

Tags: c#, .net

I have a public property with private backer like the one below. On the line `selected = Selected;` I get an SO exception. It would appear that assignment is causing some infinite recursion. Can someone give a more detailed explanation of what is happening? What should the code be instead?

```
    //other class stuff AssetTypes is an enum btw.
    private AssetTypes? selected = null;

    public AssetTypes? Selected
    {
        get
        {
            return selected;
        }
        set
        {
            selected = Selected;

            if (selected == AssetTypes.Image)
            {
                image.Click();
            }
            else if (selected == AssetTypes.Video)
            {
                video.Click();
            }
            else
            {
                selected = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

The only part that can be changed is the assignment in the setter. The if-else logic needs to be untouched.

Comment: `selected = null` not `Selected` the property.

Comment: You are assigning selected = Selected. It should be selected = value. Then set selected (not Selected) to null.

Comment: How would you know which 1/2 are wrong?  The answer you accepted was wrong at the time you accepted it.

Comment: No your app was not crashing on selected = Selected;.  Put that as the only line test.  Then try Selected = null; as the only line.  Really you left the else { Selected = null; } in the app because you cannot change the logic?

Comment: Then prove it.  Put selected = Selected; back in as the first line and it should fail.

Comment: Now I get your confusion.  So 4 answers and one comment are all wrong about the cause of the error and they don't know how to debug.  From the documentation - You cannot catch stack overflow exceptions, because the exception-handling code may require the stack.   Debug  just terminates on line it is on and it may or may not be the line  caused the recursion.   Please keep voting this down.  If selected = Selected; caused the exception the put it in as the only line and prove it.  Then put Selected = null; as the only line.

Comment: I was not talking to myself.  OP insisted the SO was caused by selected = Selected; and not by Selected = null;.  If you check the edit history Selected = Null; was changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A setter has a parameter called `value`, which is the value that the property is being set to. You should get the new value from that, not from `Selected`, which just calls the getter, which returns the previous value.

Hence, this line does nothing:

```
selected = Selected;
```

And you should never assign to `Selected` from within its own setter, because that calls the same setter, hence your infinite recursion.

Try this instead:

```
set
{        
    if (value == AssetTypes.Image)
    {
        image.Click();
        selected = value;
    }
    else if (value == AssetTypes.Video)
    {
        video.Click();
        selected = value;
    }
    else
    {
        selected = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: You down voted me for misstating recursion.  My answer perfors the proper actions.  There is image.Click() and video.Click()

Comment: Good point! Fixed. I downvoted your answer because it contains an incorrect statement about where the recursion was ("`selected = Selected` is recursion"). If you fix it, I will upvote it!

Comment: Fixed and I never down voted you.  I had to test to verify to myself that was not recursion.

Comment: Still wrong and the accepted answer.  selected == AssetTypes.Image will compare the current selected (not the value passed to the set)   And I did not vote you down nor the OP.

Answer (score 1):

You have an infinite recursion on `Selected = null`, that's why you get a stackoverflow exception. It calls over and over `Selected` set until it finally blows up with an exception. Change it by

```
selected = null;
```

Comment: He doesn't have a loop.  He has infinite recursion.  That's not a loop.

Comment: @Servy: man, I can't believe you're downvoting me because of that. I see it like a loop, but I think the point is clear and calling it a loop of recursion is not that relevant.

Comment: Using the improper term (specifically, the exact opposite term to what is correct) to describe the problem is most certainly relevant.

Comment: @Servy: I said it is a loop because it executes the same logic over an  over without stopping. That's a loop for me. I think it's sublte and it's not enough to downvote, but thanks anyway.

Comment: While I'd agree with you in some contexts, this context is exactly where the distinction matters. An infinite loop doesn't overflow the stack, but a recursion does.

Comment: @Magus: It was a mental construction to explain what was happening, I didn't mean to say that this was an infinite `for` loop. English is not my mother tongue so while I try to be as accurate as possible, I can fail to do so from time to time. Fixed in any case to avoid more controversy.

Comment: Fair enough. I certainly understand why you'd relate the two. Technically, this is an issue with C# and some other languages, but not all: every recursive call gets added to the callstack, which is the source of the problem. Now that the answer is accurate, I've upvoted it. Just leaving extra information here for the future.

Comment: @Servy: fixed the text. Even on wikipedia (and many other places) a infinite recursion is taken as a category of infinite loops. Again, I think you could have dropped a note and the downvote is exagerated.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in the else: `Selected = null`

Use `selected = null` with the lowercase s.

Greetings!

Answer (score 1):

selected = Selected does nothing

what is passed to Set is value;

```
public AssetTypes? Selected
{
    get
    {
        return selected;
    }
    set
    {
        if (selected == value) return;  // use this to not do it again

        selected = value;

        if (selected == AssetTypes.Image)
        {
            image.Click();
        }
        else if (selected == AssetTypes.Video)
        {
            video.Click();
        }
        else
        {
            selected = null;   // Selected = null; was the recursion
        }
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Selected");  // this optional and only if you implement INPC
    }
}
```

Comment: No, that's not the recursion. It just doesn't change the value. The recursion is when he assigns to `Selected`

Comment: @Blorgbeard OK,  It was broken and I posted a valid fix.

Comment: Your fix will work, but your answer still contains a wrong statement, and that `if` at the top is not necessary to prevent recursion, but changes OP's logic. Now setting the same value twice won't click the image twice.

Comment: @Blorgbeard My answer performs the proper click.  And the comment states use this to not do it again.

Comment: BTW, I have reversed my downvote into an upvote. The remaining downvote is not from me.